# pytest nested parametrization with tree-like data

Tags: python, pytest

Using pytest, I'm trying to test a tree like hierarchical scenario.
Lets use a document structure as an example:

```
Document --- Chapter --- Paragraph
       1   n        1   n
```

Where a document contains multiple chapters; a chapter contains multiple paragraphs.

When starting testing a new document, some setup code need to be run; when a new chapter is started, some other setup code need to be run; and the same for paragraph.

Written as pseudo code:

```
for doc in documents:
    setup_doc(doc)
    for chapter in doc.chapters:
        setup_chapter(chapter)
        for paragraph in chapter.paragraphs:
            setup_paragraph(paragraph)
            test_it(doc, chapter, paragraph)
            teardown_paragraph(paragraph)
        teardown_chapter(chapter)
    teardown_doc(doc)
```

If we have the following data:

```
Document Alpha
   chapter A
      Paragraph A1
      Paragraph A2
   chapter B
      Paragraph B1
```

I would expect the collected test cases to be:

```
test_it[Alpha, A, A1]
test_it[Alpha, A, A2]
test_it[Alpha, B, B1]
```

I've tried different combinations of pytest_generate_tests, class scenarios, fixtures and parametrized test functions, but have not been able to achieve this.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pytest fixutes are supposed to be independent.
So to solve your task you have to build one fixture with plain list of all features combinations (document - chapter - paragraph).

You can do that with simple fixture that returns one element of such a list or you can generate this list on test generation phase as demonstrated in the code below.

```
documents = {
        'Alpha': {
            'A': {'A1': {},'A2': {}},
            'B': {'B1': {}}
        }
    }


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    """Documents tree from documents"""
    if 'document' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        documents_plain = []
        for document in documents.keys():
            for chapter in documents[document].keys():
                for paragraph in documents[document][chapter].keys():
                    documents_plain.append({'document': document, 'chapter': chapter, 'paragraph': paragraph})
        metafunc.parametrize(
            'document',
            documents_plain,
            scope='session')


def test_it(document):
    print('{}, {}, {}'.format(document['document'], document['chapter'], document['paragraph']))


py.test -s

Alpha, B, B1
Alpha, A, A1
Alpha, A, A2
```

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you want some tests parametrized by `document`, some by `document`, `chapter` and yet others by `document`, `chapter`, `paragraph` my method (inspired by Andrey Sorokin) is as follows.

In `conftest.py`

```
import pytest

documents = {
    'Alpha': {
        'A': {'A1': {},'A2': {}},
        'B': {'B1': {}}
    }
}

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'document' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if 'chapter' in metafunc.fixturenames:
            if 'paragraph' in metafunc.fixturenames:
                metafunc.parametrize(
                    ['document', 'chapter', 'paragraph'],
                    [(d, c, p) for d, cs in documents.items()
                               for c, ps in cs.items()
                               for p in ps.keys()
                    ])
            else:
                metafunc.parametrize(
                    ['document', 'chapter'],
                    [(d, c) for d, cs in documents.items()
                            for c in cs.keys()
                    ])
        else:
            metafunc.parametrize(
                    'document', documents.keys())
```

Then in `test.py`

```
def test_d(document):
    print(document)

def test_dc(document, chapter):
    print(document, chapter)

def test_dcp(document, chapter, paragraph):
    print(document, chapter, paragraph)
```

Running

```
>>> pytest test.py -s
test.py Alpha
.Alpha A
.Alpha B
.Alpha A A2
.Alpha A A1
.Alpha B B1
.
```