# Provide default parametrization to fixtures with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

- I don't want to parametrize the same set of parameters for a bunch of tests.
- Whenever I use a fixture, I also want to use a "default parametrization". Those "default parametrization" means less `@pytest.mark.parametrize` in the code.
- Grouping the tests into a class and parametrize the whole class of tests can help in some case. But I have several combination of fixtures.

How to set "default parametrization" to fixtures? Some fixtures are classes that have several parameters.

My current solution is tedious:

```py
import pytest
import itertools

class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


def big_data():
    return [1, 2, 3]

@pytest.fixture(
    params=itertools.product(big_data(), [True, False])
)
def a(request):
    return A(*request.param)


def test_1(a):
    int(a.x + a.y)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("v", [10, 100])
def test_2(a, v):
    assert (a.x < v) or a.y
```

Comment: Maybe I can use a base class for each parametrization of a prameter. Then, I can make a class X that represents parametrization for a combination of parameters by multiple inheritance. All tests defined in class X will have the parametrization that I want. But that is just crazy.

Comment: metafunction does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818146/pytest-nested-parametrization-with-tree-like-data