# pytest nested function parametrization

Tags: python, pytest

If I have this list of tuples:

```
[(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]),

 (['d', 'e', 'f'], [4, 5, 6])]
```

How can I parametrize a test function, so the following pairs are tested:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3),
 ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3),
 ('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3),

 ('d', 4), ('d', 5), ('d', 6),
 ('e', 4), ('e', 5), ('e', 6),
 ('f', 4), ('f', 5), ('f', 6)]
```

I'm aware that two stacked decorators will combine the two lists in one of the tuples.

Comment: If you know how to do this with two stacked decorators, then why don't you do it that way? What is the problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40826505/13697228 perhaps?

Comment: If you have an example showing that it's possible with 2 stacked decorators (without having e.g. `('a', 4)`, which I think is what OP meant) would love to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`.

Example code is here:

```
import itertools

A = [(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]),
     (['d', 'e', 'f'], [4, 5, 6])]

L = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    L += list(itertools.product(A[i][0], A[i][1]))
```